# Run php in background using Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Hi I have a button on my webpage. Once I click on that button a pop up box will display and close after 2 seconds. 
Here I need to run a php code in background that contains the code for incrementing the count that the button hits.
I have given my code below 
Its not working

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,500">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="popModal.css">
</head>
<body>
    <button id="notifyModal_ex1" class="btn btn-primary">Example</button>
    <div id="content2" style="display:none">
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    </div>
    <script src="popModal.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function(){
            $('#notifyModal_ex1').click(function(){
                $('#content2').notifyModal({
                    duration : 1500,
                    placement : 'center',
                    overlay : true,
                    type : 'notify',
                    url: 'add_count.php',
                    onClose : function() {}
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: use session variable for count

Comment: how to use session vbls in this?

Comment: show `add_count.php`

Answer (score 0):

In add_count.php you define your counter - you can name it "count" and use sessions for that:

```
$_SESSION['count'] = (int)$_SESSION['count']+1;
```

And later wherever you need on front-side, you just echo your `$_SESSION['count']` variable.

Comment: however first i need to run the file., So that the session can be called

Answer (score 0):

To "run PHP in the background" you're probably going to want to make an AJAX call. Since you're using jQuery already you can use that. You can close the modal again once the PHP script returns a result; it would probably make sense to include the updated count in that so you can display it in your button.

You should do some research yourself to find out what AJAX, API's and JSON are.

Comment: 'Since you're using jQuery already you can use that' so are you saying that without jQuery it can't be done ?

Comment: @Daan, I meant that since jQuery is already loaded you could use that library's AJAX capabilities, instead of building an XMLHTTPRequest yourself or using other libs. It is always possible to do something without jQuery, because jQuery (or any other lib for that matter) is not magic.